# prettyPhoto not showing facebook button

Tags: facebook-like, prettyphoto

I have a prettyPhoto problem; Twitter button shows ok but Facebook won't. Any advice?

[Check example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sevXM.jpg)

Here is the pretty photo code part for social buttons:

```
social_tools: '<div class="twitter"><a href="http://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-count="none">Tweet</a><script type="text/javascript" src="http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"></script></div><div class="facebook"><iframe src="http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?locale=en_US&href={location_href}&amp;layout=button_count&amp;show_faces=true&amp;width=500&amp;action=like&amp;font&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=23" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:500px; height:23px;" allowTransparency="true"></iframe></div>' /* html or false to disable */
    }, pp_settings);
```

And in the prettyPhoto.css

```
.pp_social{float:left;margin:0}
.pp_social .facebook{float:left;margin-left:5px;overflow:hidden;width:55px}
.pp_social .twitter{float:left}
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to guess that it is in fact there but the twitter icon is covering it. try moving the facebook class more to the right, or align it to the left.